# Problema com buffer e/ou I2C em C

Tags: c, buffer

Espero conseguir alguma ajuda aqui. Eu estou programando para Beaglebone Black usando sensores I2C através do Eclipse IDE para C/C ++ Developers, Versão: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2).

Meu problema é com o desenvolvimento do código para o I2C, especialmente entre as funções `initializingACC` e `readingDATA` do meu código. Acho que o problema é com a variável `buf`, acredito não estar usando o buffer corretamente.

Eu desenvolvi o código abaixo, onde o comando `read` (na função `readingDATA`) só funciona se eu inserir duas linhas acima o último comando `write` (na função `initializingACC`) que fazem o último comando `write` parar de funcionar.

O objetivo do último `write` é escrever o valor 0x08 no registrador 0x2d do dispositivo I2C 0x53. É por isso que este `write` para de funcionar quando eu insiro as duas linhas (`buf [0] = ACC_OUT_LSB_X;` e `buf [1 ] = NULL;`). Por outro lado, estas linhas fazem com o que o comando `read` (na função `readingDATA`) funcione corretamente.

Eu tenho realizado os testes utilizando os comandos abaixo no terminal do Linux:

```
sudo i2cset -y 1 0x53 0x31 0x01 (Equivalente de primeira gravação para a função initializingACC)
sudo i2cset -y 1 0x53 0x08 0x2d (Equivalente de segunda gravação para a função initializingACC)
sudo i2cget -y 1 0x53 0x32 (Equivalente de ler para a função readingDATA)
```

Eis o meu código:

```c
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <linux/i2c-dev.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define ACC_ADDRESS 0x53
#define ACC_READ_ADDR  0XA7
#define ACC_PWRCTRL_ADDR  0x2D
#define ACC_MEASURE_MODE  0x08
#define ACC_DATA_FORMAT  0x31
#define ACC_OUT_LSB_X 0x32
#define ACC_OUT_MSB_X 0x33
#define ACC_OUT_LSB_Y 0x34
#define ACC_OUT_MSB_Y 0x35
#define ACC_OUT_LSB_Z 0x36
#define ACC_OUT_MSB_Z 0x37

int i2cbus = 1;
int file;
char absolute_path[20];
char buf[10];

void settingIOCTL(){

    printf("Function to set the ioctl up\n");

    snprintf(absolute_path, 19, "/dev/i2c-%d", i2cbus);
    file = open(absolute_path, O_RDWR);
    if (file < 0) {
        // ERROR HANDLING; you can check errno to see what went wrong
        exit(1);
    }
    if (ioctl(file, I2C_SLAVE, ACC_ADDRESS) < 0) {
        // ERROR HANDLING; you can check errno to see what went wrong
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Function to set the ioctl up processed\n");
}
void initializingACC(){

    printf("function to initialize\n");

    // Using I2C Write
    buf[0] = ACC_DATA_FORMAT;
    buf[1] = 0x01;
    if (write(file, buf, 2) != 2) { // Equivalent of sudo i2cset -y 1 0x53 0x31 0x01
        // ERROR HANDLING: i2c transaction failed
        }
    buf[0] = ACC_PWRCTRL_ADDR;
    buf[1] = ACC_MEASURE_MODE;

    /*These 2 lines below predictably make this function stop working (next writing)
      otherside, them make the next function (readingDATA/read) work properly*/
    buf[0] = ACC_OUT_LSB_X;
    buf[1] = NULL;

    if (write(file, buf, 2) != 2) { // Equivalent of sudo i2cset -y 1 0x53 0x2d 0x08
        // ERROR HANDLING: i2c transaction failed
        }
    printf("Function to initialize processed\n");
}

void readingDATA(int register_address){

    printf("Function to read\n");

    buf[0] = register_address; //I thought this line would be above the reading line but it makes the reading stop working
    // Using I2C Read
    if (read(file, buf, 1) != 1) { // Equivalent of sudo i2cset -y 1 0x53 0x2d 0x08
        // ERROR HANDLING: i2c transaction failed
     } else {
             // buf[0] contains the read byte
             printf("read byte: %x\n",buf[0]);
     }
  printf("Function to read processed\n");
}

int main(void){

      settingIOCTL();
      initializingACC();
      readingDATA(ACC_OUT_LSB_X);

      return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 por ter postado o código completo e detalhando o que você está fazendo com ele e de uma forma clara e bem-escrita. Queria tanto que todos os novos usuários fossem assim...